# How to implement a C++ serializer the idiomatic way?

Tags: c++, json, serialization, boost, stl

As an exercise, I'm implementing an [UBJson](http://ubjson.org/) serializer in several languages. My question is: is there an idiomatic way to imlpement a custom format reader and writer in C++ ? For example, I thought of implementing another boost::serialization  archive type.

More details : the type-introspection part is not a problem - if I ever use my implementation, it's to replace an already present json serializer. I also understand the notion of recursive serialization. The real question is : should I create readInt, writeString methods, or just make two templated read and write methods, or... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I'm not aware of any idiomatic ways, though the standard strategy I am aware of is to only serializer the simplest of types. One could recursively break down a complex object into simpler pieces until the base `POD` types, such as `int`, `char *`, `float` are found. Then hand-made serialization routines for these base types are created.

Serialization of more complex types involves this recursive type introspection which results in a larger serialization routine built from smaller ones.

This sort of approach would however require some form of type introspection in C++, which turns out to be much more involved than the serialization itself. Here's an article I wrote on the topic: http://www.randygaul.net/2013/01/05/c-reflection-part-5-automated-serialization/

There are two main ways to write the actual serialization routines. The first way is to create a single serialization function that takes a `bool` for input/output.

```
void Serialize( type instance, bool input );
```

The second way is to write input and output as separate functions (which I myself prefer):

```
void Serialize( type instance );
Variant Deserialize( type info );
```

Templating the serialization routines, or just providing specific overloads is a matter of preference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I updated my question, which was way too generic.

Comment: @gracchus I see. Well my response to that would be to do whatever you like. Generally a templated `POD` serializer works so long as the stream or file object supports overloading for all required base types. I myself like `fprintf` and so I specialized all of my base routines. I tried updating my answer a little bit to answer your question better.